# Подключение и работа с Web-Service

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Добрый день!**

Передо мной стоит задача:

1. Подключиться к веб-сервису по имени.
2. Получить список методов на сервисе и количество параметров каждого.
3. Иметь возможность вызвать каждый из методов и задавать параметры выбранного метода.

Единственное, что у меня пока получилось, - это подключиться к веб-сервису соседнего проекта и вывести у себя на странице HelloWorld().

Мне кажется, что тут нужно копать в сторону **HttpWebRequest**, но как именно, непонятно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать, может, статьи где полезные есть, сам я не нашел еще. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

**Обновление**

Ошибка, точнее проблема в том, что я не знаю, как получить список методов веб-сервиса. По ходу дела  нужно использовать wdsl, но как именно, ума не приложу. Вот в этом проблема. Т.е. по адресу сервиса получить список его методов. Спасибо!

Comment: @Leonard Bertone, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Простите, Вы правы. Я недописал. Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предпочитаю для таких вещей использовать более подходящий язык программирования. Но раз предпочитаете C#, то вот небольшой пример:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-Mono_11/
А еще погуглите на предмет получения курсов валют с сайта Центробанка. Найдете много примеров на C#.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Проблема с подключением решена. Вы случайно не знаете, как прочитать wsdl-файлик и считать оттуда все методы вебсервера?

Comment: Я это делал только в джаве, в среде IntellijIdea. Там автоматом генерятся функции, исходя из содержимого wsdl.

Comment: Пришел из гугла и меня опять в гугл отправляют (

Answer (score 1):

При поиске в гугле по запросу "работа с веб службами c#" ссылка на эту страничку выдается первой в списке или одной из первых, а ответа здесь толком нет, есть ссылка только на сторонний ресурс (на сколько он надежен? на сколько удачен и применим тот пример?) и отсылка обратно в гугл, поэтому я напишу этот ответ (возможно для себя самого в будущем).

Я создал пустой проект по шаблону `Console App` в `Visual Studio`. Добавим ссылку на веб-службу: правый клик в `Solution Explorer` по `References`, выбрать `Add Service Reference...`. Нажать внизу слева кнопку `Advanced...`, в появившемся окне слева внизу нажать `Add Web Reference...`. В поле `URL` необходимо вставить ссылку на asmx-файл веб службы. Я вставил туда ссылку на веб службу всеми любимого ЦБРФ API: `http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx`. Нажать `Enter` или кнопку со стрелочкой. После загрузки прописать в `Web reference name` удобное имя, оно будет использоваться как пространство имен для этой службы, я написал `Cbrf`. Нажать `Add Reference...`
Всё. В `Solution Explorer` в вашем проекте появится папка `Web Refereces` и элемент `Cbrf` в ней. Теперь можно подключиться:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using TestWebService.Cbrf;

namespace TestWebService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var di = new DailyInfo();
            var curs = di.GetCursOnDateXML(DateTime.Today);
            foreach (XmlNode node in curs.ChildNodes)
                Console.WriteLine(node["Vnom"].InnerText + " "
                                + node["Vname"].InnerText.Trim() + " = " 
                                + node["Vcurs"].InnerText + " руб.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

PS. Вопросы актуальности использования таких веб служб, а также удобства использования пространства имен `System.Xml` я не затрагиваю. Хотя в этом конкретном примере я бы предпочел не использовать веб службу, а воспользоваться [XML-сервисом получения данных](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/Root.asp?PrtId=SXML) в связке с `XmlSerializer` или `XDocument`

Comment: Уважаемый Андрей NOP! Я не могу писать комментарии, поэтому приходится как-бы отвечать на вопрос... Ваш ответ мне ОЧЕНЬ помог! Только одно дополнеие: http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?WSDL - только так добавляется WebReference. Без "WSDL" выдает ошибку... Еще раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: Отлично, рад что оказалось полезным. Когда у вас будет возможность голосовать за ответы, просто проголосуйте здесь.